# How do I run multiple versions of PHP on OS 10.9?

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've install multiple versions of PHP on my Mac with Apache 2.2.26 all via Brew. I was wondering if it's possible to have them all running on Apache in special cases such as for specific virtual hosts.

The way I see it is something like this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # LoadModule php53
    ServerName "php53"
    DocumentRoot "/www/php53"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # LoadModule php54
    ServerName "php54"
    DocumentRoot "/www/php54"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # LoadModule php55
    ServerName "php55"
    DocumentRoot "/www/php55"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I tried that method it only used the first defined php module, where ideally I would like a default PHP version used (php55) unless defined within that case.

Also, I would like to do something similar within the terminal. So call `$ php` will be my default (php55) but then I could do `$ php53` and do stuff with that version.

Would like to try this approach first before looking down the Vagrant route.

Comment: Would it matter in your case if you do not use the php5 module, but run several instances of php-fpm/fcgi and let each virtual host be handled by a different port? If you can do that: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM (per vhost config)

Comment: i use since many years mamp pro for such needs. You can just select the PHP version you need from the configuration GUI and restart the server. Check out http://www.mamp.info/de/mamp-pro/ for more information. Another option would be to use php in cgi mode instead of a module mod. You than would be able to define for each site by configuration (.httaccess file) which php version shall be used.